# Can I have solid lines instead of Cdots/Vdots in nicematrix?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

Loading the `nicematrix` package, the code

```
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[last-col,nullify-dots, margin]
    & & & \\
    \Cdots & A_j & \Cdots & i\\
    & & &
\end{bNiceMatrix}
```

generates this:

[image]

Can I get the dotted lines to be replaced with solid lines to get something analogous to the following?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots/line-style=solid}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[last-col,nullify-dots, margin]
    & & & \\
    \Cdots & A_j &\Cdots & i\\
    & & &
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Is there some documentation where I can read these techniques?

Comment: Another question: I guess this will affect the `line-style` globally. How can I restore that to default settings?

Comment: The customization of the dotted lines (created by `\Cdots`, etc.) is documented in the page 27 of the official documentation of  `nicematrix` (file `nicematrix.pdf` available for example on CTAN). You can use the key `xdots` (with its subkey `line-style`) locally for an environment or for a single command `\Cdots`.

Comment: Can one also have a mix of dotted and dashed lines as my desired output shows? I don't think it is possible by the option you suggest (though it fulfils the current requirement).